# Is Spring UriTemplate thread safe?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to reuse the same UriTemplate instance instead of creating it every time. But I don't know whether it is thread safe or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UriTemplate accepts a URI String which it decomposes into:

- `private final String uriTemplate;`
- `private final UriComponents uriComponents;`
- `private final List<String> variableNames;`
- `private final Pattern matchPattern;`

This encapsulated state is populated in `UriTemplate`'s only constructor. The public methods on `UriTemplate` do not change this state and they do not expose it in a way which could be changed by external invokers. And, of course, the types of this internal state are immutable.

So, yes, `UriTemplate` is thread safe.

Minor caveat; the Javadocs do not *explicitly state* that it is thread safe so it might not necessarily remain that way.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and teach me how to identify that :)